# create contact importer for my web site from yahoo for now

Tags: php, contacts, yahoo-api

I try to create contact importer for my website
I read this page: http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-requesttoken.html
I create code like this:

```
<?php
$time = time();
$key = 

'dj0yJmk9c21MVnlUNnlpcTFwJmQ9WVdrOU5tWmtWVVE0Tm0wbWNHbzlNVEkyTmpreE1qYzJNZy0tJxxxxxx';
$secret = '58b907a5a67caf9cd837821c53fxxxxxxxx';
header("location: https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?oauth_nonce=ce2130523f788f313f76314ed3965ea6&oauth_timestamp=$time&oauth_consumer_key=$key&oauth_signature_method=plaintext&oauth_signature=$secret&oauth_version=1.0&xoauth_lang_pref=\"en-us\"&oauth_callback=\"http://mysite/yahoo.php\"");
```

?>
but I get not found page when its go to yahoo !
what is problem?

Comment: What happens if you point your browser to `http://mysite/yahoo.php`?

Comment: its go to yahoo and show not found page in yahoo !

Answer (score 0):

problem solved
we must use firebug for see error with oauth
because when something wrong with your code
yahoo return 401 error and we just see not found page
but firebug show you what is your code problem
and you can solve it